# How to send a QString to debug output?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt5, qdebug

I cannot print out a QString in Qt using QDebug.

Below are some attempts (none work):

```
    QDebug(letters.toStdString());
    QDebug(letters.toLatin1());
    QDebug() << letters.toUtf8();
    QDebug() << letters.toWCharArray();
    QDebug() << letters.toStdString();
    QDebug() << letters;
```

I have included:

```
#include <QtDebug>
#include <QDebug>
```

I am using Qt 5.2. I also added `CONFIG += console` to my project file

My error is "no matching function for call to QDebug::QDebug()"

I also got "QDebug(QByteArray) is ambiguous" for `QDebug(letters.toLatin1());`

Comment: What error do you get ?

Comment: you should use it a little different way: `qDebug() << letters;`

Comment: @SirDarius I edited the question to answer you.

Comment: @mexus Look at the sixth attempt

Comment: QDebug and qDebug are not the same...

Comment: @user929404 Look at the lower-case letter `q` in my comment

Comment: That was pretty dumb of me. Sorry guys

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The correct way to do so is:

```
#include <QDebug>

// snip...

QString letters;

qDebug() << letters;
```

Be careful to use `qDebug()` beginning with a small letter, since it is not the same thing as the `QDebug` class.

See http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qtglobal.html#qDebug. It is a convenience function that returns an already configured QDebug object.

Comment: That is what I have done and it doesn't work

Comment: @user929404 it is `qDebug` and not `QDebug`. Read. Don't guess.

Comment: worth to mention that you can print QString with qDebug("%s", qPrintable(qstring_instance));